# Block USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED on specified device

Tags: android, usb

I have an app that opens when the user connects an USB device. It all works fine.
What I need is to block this feature only for one specified device.
In AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".ConnectUSB"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
```

The ConnectUSB class:

```
public class ConnectUSB extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectUSB.this, MainProg.class);
        intent.putExtra(MainProg.RUN_USB, true);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

If I add an if to this class, like:

`boolean doNotStart= "Device".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.BRAND) && "XXX".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MODEL);`

and use `startActivity` only when it's false there remains a blank screen.

If I use `finish` when it's true there is a white blink on the display.

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

doesn't `device_filter` work for you? you can declare in there which devices you can handle

also you may use `Service` (overview in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)) for listening this `intent-filter`, which will fire in the background. check in there if attached device is "yours" and if it is then `startActivity`

Comment: The `device_filter` works fine but I want this filter not to work only on one specified device.
I'll check the `Service`. Thank you.